# filter datagridviwe by datetimepicker and show result

Tags: c#, datagridview, datetimepicker

I have a column called DOB on datagridview 
and I have two datetimepickers above. I want to show just records that have DOB date in the range of my two datetimepicker when I click the load button

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is assumed that the `DataGridView` has it's `DataSource` set to a 
    `DataTable`.
2. Now, lets take dtp1 , dtp2 as the two `DateTimePickers`
3. I have named the first column of `DataTable` as dob, 2nd as age, 3rd as 
      name.

The following is the code for Load button.

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //validation
    if (DateTime.Compare(dtp1.Value.Date, dtp2.Value.Date) > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The start date cannot be greater than the end 
        date.");
        dtp1.Focus();
        return;
    }

    DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgv.DataSource;
    DataView dv = new DataView();
    dv = dt.DefaultView;
    dv.RowFilter = "dob >= '" + dtp1.Value.Date + "' and  dob <= '" +   
    dtp2.Value.Date + "'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to change your sql query to select where the DOB value is greater than your start date and less than your end date...

This is a very basic example that binds the datagridview with such a selection.

I've written this from memory and I haven't done anything this way for many years so I make no guarantees about whether this works or not but it should get you started.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DOB > @startdate and DOB < @enddate";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@startdate", DateTimePicker1.Date));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@enddate", DateTimePicker2.Date));

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
DataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: thanks for your response:) but i don't have database to connect with it my app is like excel sheets generator

Comment: You should be able to use the SQL query anyway, but I see you've accepted another answer already so I won't get into all of that